# Selecet Column Name From a particular Table Where that Column doesn't containing any value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a sql query which returns all the column name which doesn't containing any value...
For example I have a table ABC which have Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4,Col5, Col6...

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Col1       Col2       Col3        Col4          Col5         Col6
-----------------------------------------------------------------
asd         asd       asd         asda                           
asdas                 asdasd      asdd          
           asdsd                   asdsd        asdasd
asdasd      asdas      asdasd      asdsad         asda
```

---

Hence that query will return Col6.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with something like:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when count(col1) = 0 then 'col1' end),
                 (case when count(col2) = 0 then 'col2' end),
                 (case when count(col3) = 0 then 'col3' end),
                 (case when count(col4) = 0 then 'col4' end),
                 (case when count(col5) = 0 then 'col5' end),
                 (case when count(col6) = 0 then 'col6' end),
                )
from t;
```